# Maximum static load on a wooden king post truss

Tags: structural-analysis

I have a garage with a roof which has a wooden king post truss that spans 4m ( with a total of 14 trusses spaced 450-550mm apart). Roof pitch is 35deg, and beam dimensions are 38mmx90mm, soft wood I am guessing C16, with modern stamped metal joints.

I was expecting to find a simple table or calculation which would give me the maximum distributed static roof loading which I am expecting to be 0.75kN/m2 but after many hours of searching I am struggling to find anything.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aaah the art of safety factors in civil engineering... Reason you may be lacking literature is that 38mmX90mm is commonly referred to as a 2x4.  Don't forget to account for the weight of your roofing!

Comment: Thanks Abel, but data on 2x4 doesn't seem to be any better. Really surprised that there are no look-up tables on this, and I have hunted hard. Any references appreciated !

Comment: The CivE approach. (Wander the maze some more).. https://www.nachi.org/structural-design-wood-framing-home-inspector.htm. Or bypass it and go the mechE approach https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.engineeringtoolbox.com/amp/wood-beams-strength-d_1480.html and model as beams...